# how to automate dependency resolution (local and remote) in node

Tags: node.js

I have a very small data-cap so I want to install dependencies for node projects by first linking to whatever it finds installed on local machine and fetching remotely if not found locally. I don't want to manually go through all the require statements in the apps because theres a lot of them - is there a node way to do this?

eg. this except not manually determining what is or isn't installed

```
Project A
    npm install -g connect
    npm install -g serve-static
```

then later

```
Project B
   npm link connect
   npm link serve-static
```

Comment: You don't need to "go through all the require statements," you just need to read `package.json`.

Comment: I'm confused, doesn't NPM already have caching built in by default? https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache

Comment: it does, definitely, but you ll need to fetch it once at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred way to go about dependency management is with a `package.json`.
To get started with one of these in a project, run `npm init`, and answer all the questions. This will leave you with a file like this:

```
{
  "name": "test-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A test project",
  "main": "test.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Josh",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Once this is in place, add the `--save` flag to each of your `npm install` commands. For example, if you run `npm install --save connect`, your package.json changes to this

```
{
  "name": "test-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A test project",
  "main": "test.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Josh",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "connect": "^3.3.5"
  }
}
```

Now whenever you need to install the project's dependencies, run `npm install`, and all the dependencies listed in the `package.json` will be automatically installed.